Getting into deep S0ix ('modern standby')
I observed that when put into standby mode, my computer (Thinkpad T14 Gen 5 with an Intel(R) Core(TM) Ultra 5 125U, running Fedora 40, kernel-6.10.11) still gets very warm and drains its battery, although the screen is switched off, and the power led flashes like indicating standby mode. After digging, I learned about S0ix (dubbed 'modern standby'), and that my computer apparently does not support the old-fashioned S3 standby anymore (/sys/power/mem_sleep reads [s2idle], nothing more). Digging deeper, I found the S0ix self test tool, which says
...
Your system only get shallower S0ix substate residency: S0i2.1 1938299461

Need to debug why not deeper substate: S0i2.2
...
Below are the deeper S0ix substate required IPs did not show YES:

 pmc0:               AON3_OFF_STS    Required             
pmc0:           XTAL_LVM_OFF_STS    Required             
pmc0:          XTAL_AGGR_OFF_STS    Required             
pmc0:         FILTER_PLL_OFF_STS    Required             
pmc0:            SOC_PLL_OFF_STS    Required             
pmc0: IOE_COND_MET_S02I2_2_REQ_STS    Required             
pmc0:           ARC_IDLE_REQ_STS    Required             
pmc0: ARC_INTERRUPT_WAKE_REQ_STS    Required             
pmc1:               AON2_OFF_STS    Required             
pmc1:               AON3_OFF_STS    Required             
pmc1:           AON3_SPL_OFF_STS    Required             
pmc1:          XTAL_AGGR_OFF_STS    Required             
pmc1:            SOC_PLL_OFF_STS    Required             
pmc1:           SBR0_PGD0_PG_STS    Required             
pmc1:           SBR1_PGD0_PG_STS    Required             
pmc1:           SBR2_PGD0_PG_STS    Required             
pmc1:           SBR3_PGD0_PG_STS    Required             
pmc1:           SBR4_PGD0_PG_STS    Required             
pmc1:        IOE_D2D_PGD1_PG_STS    Required               


Please check the potential blockers

(the full output is pasted here). I assume that this is related to my problem; however, I have way too little knowledge of linux in general and Linux power management in particular.
Does anybody have ideas about a potential solution?

What is the exact processor model in ypur laptop?  I do not think SOix is supported o Meteor Lake processors such as the Intel Core Ultra 7 155H

@fpmurphy I added the CPU. That would be unfortunate; since S3 seems also not to be supported anymore. So, no sleep on current CPU?
